# Local notifications using ACR notifications plugin in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, notifications, local

I am creating a bunch of notifications using ARC notification plugin for xamarin and all of them are sent immediately after I open the app despite the fact that I am setting the date and time at least one day away from the current date.  My question is, how can I set up the Notification model so that I am receiving the notification at the specified date/time?

```
var notif = new Notification(){
        Id = count++,
        Date = item.PostDate.Date,
        Title = item.Type.Equals(DayType.Duminica)
            ? item.Title
            : $"{item.Title} {Helpers.GetCurrentDateOldFormat(item.PostDate.AddDays(-13))}",
        Message = item.Content,                                
        When = App.Settings.NotificationTime // new TimeSpan(08, 00, 00)
};
```

Comment: Is it ARC or ACR Notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It will help you.

**Send a scheduled notification:**

```
App.Settings.NotificationTime = TimeSpan.FromDays(50); 

var id = await CrossNotifications.Current.Send(
    item.Type.Equals(DayType.Duminica) ? item.Title : $"{item.Title} {Helpers.GetCurrentDateOldFormat(item.PostDate.AddDays(-13))}",
    item.Content,
    when = App.Settings.NotificationTime);
```

For more information [click here](https://github.com/aritchie/notifications).

Comment: Thanks for your response. We migrated to push notifications which is a better alternative all around.

Comment: How do you set the time of the notification?